# How do companies charge for items on cdn sites?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, cdn

I've been looking at several different possible jQuery and ASP.NET MVC components.  Several of the companies seem to host the entire javascript code on their CDN sites.  For example, a company who's name is a combination of Telephone and the nickname of Richard, has a free of charge jQuery UI set of applications, but they charge for their grid and a few other components.  However, the css and js files needed for the grid are hosted on a cdn site.  What's to stop any developer from just referencing them, or downloading the file to their own site for free?

Not asking to try and pirate anything, but it just seems confusing to me.

Comment: They pay attention to your use then block you (prevent CORS access) if you don't comply with their policies. Either that, or they don't allow CORS access in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, several options:

a) Code that includes a trackback of some kind. Examples:

- css/html that references an image hosted on an external source.When the image is downloaded, it can be tracked
- javascript that includes a hidden link, or pings (ajax posts) to parent website. The javascript itself might be obfuscated.

b) The charge is maybe for the support (developer feedback, customer support, access to source code and the like)

and last but not least,
c) The good heart/morals of the developer who will respect the terms of use, seeing that himself/herself would like to get paid for his/her work.